# No module named RPi.GPIO even though it's installed

Tags: python, pip

When running code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import MFRC522
import signal

continue_reading = True

# Capture SIGINT for cleanup when the script is aborted
def end_read(signal,frame):
    global continue_reading
    print "Ctrl+C captured, ending read."
    continue_reading = False
    GPIO.cleanup()
...
```

I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "Read.py", line 1, in 
> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
> ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO

I've checked out many answers on stackexchange about this but cannot get the solutions to work.

I've tried,

**pip install RPi.GPIO**

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: RPi.GPIO in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.7.0)
```

**sudo apt install RPi.GPIO**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python3-rpi.gpio' for regex 'RPi.GPIO'
Note, selecting 'python-rpi.gpio' for regex 'RPi.GPIO'
Note, selecting 'rpi.gpio-common' for regex 'RPi.GPIO'
python3-rpi.gpio is already the newest version (0.7.0-0.2+b1).
rpi.gpio-common is already the newest version (0.7.0-0.2+b1).
rpi.gpio-common set to manually installed.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfuse2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
```

**sudo apt install python-rpi.gpio**

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-rpi.gpio
Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Reading package lists... Done             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python-rpi.gpio is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-rpi.gpio' has no installation candidate
```

I'm using python 2.7.18 on latest rasbian image.

I'm following this guide [here](https://www.instructables.com/RFID-RC522-Raspberry-Pi/) for using an RFID reader

Comment: Python 2.X is no longer supported. You have a version of RPi.GPIO installed which supports Python3.

Comment: There is no need to do anything. RPi.GPIO is included in the image. I suggest you start again to remove all the mess you have installed (preferably a fresh install) AND DO NOT install obsolete python 2.

Comment: To make matters worse the packages installed by pip are not for Bullseye.

Comment: But when I try python3 I get errors about the print(" and print " mismatch. I'd have to change hundreds of lines in the library files too.

Comment: The project description page says 2.7 is supported https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/#description

Comment: Take a look at 2to3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20458067/7467472

Comment: Python2 is not supported with current versions of RaspiOS. So what are you installing?

Comment: I'm using the latest rasbian release using the rasberry image writer tool

Comment: It's impossible to get an RC522 RFID module to work with raspberry pi using any of the top 10 guides on google. I've tried them all, even got a new RPi and new RFID modules. It's a total no-go.